# How do I automatically create a section if it doesn't exist?

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

If I try to write to a section that doesn't exist yet, I get a `configparser.NoSectionError`:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

c = ConfigParser()

c['a'] = {'x': 1}
c['a']['y'] = '2'
c.set(section='a', option='z', value='3')

for i in c:
    print(f'Section {i}:')
    for j in c[i]:
        print(f'\t{j}: {c[i][j]}')

# KeyError
c['b']['u'] = '0'

# NoSectionError
c.set('b', 'u', '0')
```

Is there really no way of asking `ConfigParser` to set a value, and create the section if it doesn't exist? Checking for whether a section exists, and creating it every time seems like a tedious design.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done directly. However, there is a trade-off based on the `read_dict` method that exists for ConfigParser objects. The idea is to define a fake dictionary that only contains section names, each of them being associated to an empty dictionary. Here is the trick inserted in your previous code:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

c = ConfigParser()
c.read_dict({'a':{},'b':{},'c':{}})

c['a']['x'] = '1'
c['a']['y'] = '2'
c.set(section='a', option='z', value='3')
c['b']['u'] = '0'
c.set('c', 'v', '0')

for i in c:
    print(f'Section {i}:')
    for j in c[i]:
        print(f'\t{j}: {c[i][j]}')
```

As you can see: no more errors and no need to use `add_section()` for each new section name.

But of course, you may define something more useful than a fake dictionary. For instance, the whole config structure given above may be created with a single line:

```
c.read_dict(dict(a=dict(x=1, y=2, z=3), b=dict(u=0), c=dict(v=0)))
```

or with the alternative syntax:

```
c.read_dict({'a':{'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}, 'b':{'u':0}, 'c':{'v':0}})
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as just creating all the sections when initializing the ConfigParser?

Comment: @Donentolon: If you know all your section names, you may of course create the empty section dictionary when creating the ConfigParser. The advantage of `read_dict` is that it may be called several times, for instance when you have to merge several INI files, or extend an existing INI file with additional sections. Actually, my answer was an answer to the request in your OP, where you asked for a solution to create arbitrary key/value pairs without having to check and use `add_sections` before.